# UPDATE MYSQL TABLE WITH FOR LOOP IN PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to update 2 columns, `rated` and `imdb_rating` for all the values in a mysql table from an array in php. `$data` is a 2-dimensional array. The array is posted from javascript. No error is shown and everything seems to be OK except nothing is happening in my table; no record is updating. `echo json_encode(0)` does return 0 but no record is updating. My biggest worry is that `die(mysqli_error($con));` is not returning any error. Where did I go wrong?

```
if($con){
        $data=$_POST['dat'];
        $count=sizeof($data);

        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $sql="UPDATE `movies2` SET `rated`='$data[$i][2]' WHERE `movie_ID`='$data[$i][0]'";
        $sql2="UPDATE `movies2` SET `imdb_rating`='$data[$i][1]' WHERE `movie_ID`='$data[$i][0]'";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $result2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
    }

        if($result && $result2){
            echo json_encode(0);
        }
        else{
            echo json_encode(1);
            die(mysqli_error($con));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not include raw $_POST data inside your query. Read about SQL injection. Did you try to echo your queries? You will see what's wrong with them.

Comment: If you `echo` `$sql` and `$sql2`, are the values properly filled in as you'd expect? If you copy/paste that query in phpMyAdmin, does it update the database properly?

Comment: Yes the sql statements work just fine in phpMyAdmin

Comment: Syntax is wrong, you can't write "$data[$i][2]" because "[2]" is treated as string, not array index. You need to write "{$data[$i][2]}" but don't build query like this anyway. Use PDO instead.

Comment: "the sql statements work" - did you ECHO those queries or just manually write in phpMyAdmin? It makes big difference.

Comment: Btw, what is "$result $$ $result2"? There is no "$$" in php.

Comment: It says 'array to string conversion' in `$sql` and `$sql2`

Comment: mind editing your title so that it's not in CAPS? It's considered as shouting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think This may work for you.

[image: If Database Like Be]

If Your `$_POST['dat']` be like below.

```
      <?php
            $_POST['dat']= array(array('1234','imdb_rating1','rated1'),array('2345','imdb_rating2','rated2'));

            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $database = 'test';

        $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
        if($con){
        $data=$_POST['dat'];
        $count=sizeof($data);

        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
          $data0 =  $data[$i][0];
          $data1 =  $data[$i][1];
          $data2 =  $data[$i][2];
        $sql="UPDATE `movies2` SET `imdb_rating`='".$data1."', `rated`='".$data2."' WHERE `movie_ID`='".$data0."'";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    }

        if($result){
            echo json_encode(0);
        }
        else{
            echo json_encode(1);
            die(mysqli_error($con));
        }
    }
                ?>
```

[image: Result Will Be Like]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the error was in `$data[$i][2]`. Using `{$data[$i][2]}` instead worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are no special libraries in the standard PHP installation and string concatenation is implemented using the dot operator: change your code like this.

```
$sql="UPDATE `movies2` SET `rated`='".$data[$i][2]."' WHERE `movie_ID`='".$data[$i][0]."'";
```

$sql2="UPDATE `movies2` SET `imdb_rating`='".$data[$i][1]."' WHERE `movie_ID`='".$data[$i][0]."'";